# How to run executable (application/x-executable)

Tags: files

I downloaded the linux version of [this](http://w84death.itch.io/tanks-of-freedom/download/eyJleHBpcmVzIjoxNDI1OTc1ODg2LCJpZCI6MTc3MDV9.XFAoge%2Flay08Ol1q0%2FopxNkoB18%3D) game and go a zip

inside the zip is a application/x-executable file which I can't run. ./filename does nothing as well as sh filename.

EDIT: I meant this game. the one above is already a bin
http://surger1.itch.io/chronoclysm

Comment: What is the file name and extension?

Comment: Please run `uname -m` and `file [filename]` and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

are you running a 64 bit platform of linux
as this is a 64 bit app?
i downloaded 
chmoded the file
like so

```
chmod +x ToF_Beta2.065_linux64.bin
```

then i ran like this

```
./ToF_Beta2.065_linux64.bin
```

and it run perfect :)

but im 64 bit ubuntu

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you chmod it +x 
you can also try

```
sh programname
```

Comment: I get unwind.x86: 1: unwind.x86: ELF4��4: not found
unwind.x86: 2: unwind.x86: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing some corresponding libraries for the platform the game was compiled for. What distribution do you use? I'm asking because on Ubuntu 12.04 you could simply install the i386-libraries with

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

On 14.04 LTS you have to do something like:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

**Please note:** The second example is only a dirty hack by forcing Trusty to use an older repository.